# Application to fill in Dynamic PDF on mobile devices

Tags: android, pdf, ios, pdf-viewer

Is there an application that allows you to to fill in **dynamic** PDF form (XFA forms) on mobile devices (especially Android and iOS)? The form should be available **offline** ([the solution using HTML5 form created with Adobe LifeCycle from the original PDF](https://helpx.adobe.com/livecycle/kb/xfa-pdf-forms-policy-protected-documents-not-displayed.html) seems to not be acceptable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adobe has said no](http://www.planetpdf.com/enterprise/article.asp?ContentID=Adobe_says_No_to_XFA_support_in_Adobe_Reader_Mobile&gid=8457) to supporting XFA in their mobile versions of Acrobat before. I am not aware of anything that will render XFA forms on mobile devices natively, most things convert to HTML 5 for displaying them on mobile devices.

There is a similar question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4097348/924) about this and it seems no one has found a solution that does this natively.

[PDFium](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/) would most likely be the best place to start looking.

Comment: Well I already knew that XFA was not supported by Adobe (I have read the blog article referenced by the article you put as link). As I have read, XFA branch seems to also be deprecated in PDFium. Have you any experience with it?.

Comment: @C.Champagne I don't personally have any experience with PDFium, I know a few people who have worked with it and are more experienced in the PDF field that myself. If your XFA forms are pretty simple and don't push the boundaries of the specification, things should work pretty well. The edge/boundary conditions are where it gets tricky to support everything perfectly.

I don't think PDFium deprecated support for it, it looks like they deprecated the branch in their source control that was specific to the XFA feature. It still seems to be supported on the mainline of code.